# UITableView edit mode delete button padding-right

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, editmode

I want to give some space between `UITableView` **edit mode delete button** and cell **left side** (See screenshot below).
Any idea?
[image]
<sub>(source: [mixdesign.kz](http://mixdesign.kz/mix/editmode.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@property(nonatomic) NSInteger indentationLevel is a property define din [UITableViewCell documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/indentationLevel). Using this you can set the indentation level of a tableview Cell. Set this property from your `- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state`

Answer (score 2):

Setting indentationLevel/indentationWidth did not work for me.

What worked for me was subclassing UITableViewCell and customized `-layoutSubviews`:

```
#define LEFT_EDITING_MARGIN 42

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (self.editing && self.contentView.frame.origin.x != 0) {
        CGRect frame = self.contentView.frame;
        CGFloat diff = LEFT_EDITING_MARGIN - frame.origin.x;
        frame.origin.x = LEFT_EDITING_MARGIN;
        frame.size.width -= diff;
        self.contentView.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implements

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
```

in your UITableViewCell subclass to slightly move your subviews in order to have a larger padding.